# Retained mode graphics for iOS

Tags: ios, graphics

**Preamble:** I occasionally do 2D business graphics development but have not yet done so on iOS or OSX. I do not consider myself a graphics expert by any stretch of the imagination but I have learned, for the type of graphics and UI programming I do, retained mode graphics makes far more sense than immediate mode graphics. So my question does not relate to whether or not retained or immediate mode is better or when to use etc. I clearly know that I want to use retained mode graphics. In the past I have had to develop UI's that contained large amounts of 2D graphics in Java (Swing applications using the Java2D library). Java2D was all very immediate mode stuff and very procedural.  Subsequently I have had a look at JavaFX and all of this has changed with a very unified UI and graphics model that is very much a great retained mode graphics system.

I have just started iOS development and so far I am still scratching my head a bit - Core, Quartz, Cocoa, OpenGl ES, SpriteKit, SceneKit... etc.

**Question:**  Is there a good Apple retained mode graphics solution for iOS development for 2D business graphics solutions?